# 15" MacBook Pro to 27" iMac monitor

Tags: imac, thunderbolt

Can I hook up my 15" macbook Pro thunderbolt to my 27" iMac thunderbolt, and operate the MacBook pro in Windows 7 in order to have a large monitor to run AutoCad?

Both computers are running OSX Yosemite and Bootcamp Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Target Display Mode: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3924), you can't do it.

> **8. Can I use TDM in Boot Camp?**
>
> Target Display Mode is not supported under Boot Camp.

Comment: Bootcamp is nog supported, but I think TDM is supported when using a virtual machine to run windows